# array removal of elements based on the first letter of element for RUBY

Tags: ruby

I went to http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002198 and can't figure out the way to take an array of names for example

```
people = [chris,george,jerry,bob,bill,julie,josh]
```

I want to be able to have the user select a letter "b" then hit enter and extract all elements with the first letter 'b' and put them in a seperate array. In this case it would be [bob,bill]
The .slice command should work for this but I don't know how to tell it to just look at the first letter of the elements? Would that be some sort of a argument that would need to be filled like this people.slice()

```
people_selector = gets.chomp.to_s
people.slice(people_selector)
print people
```

Google is no help either, unfortunately. Post code so I can look at argument values please.

Comment: Ok I understand the pipes and how to go through the elements, lots of different ways to be done in Ruby. One thing I did come across case sensitivity while using methods. how do I edit my gets.chomp to accept a & A if that is the value entered?

Comment: You can use the `i` flag on a regular expression match or use `downcase` to adjust the letter you're looking at and the item you're searching for.

Comment: That is, say, `people.partition {|x| x[0,1].match(/letter/i) }`

Comment: or `people.partition {|x| x =~ /^letter/i}` - if you're using regexps you can anchor to the start of the word rather than extract the first letter

Answer (score 9):

You probably want [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002191), not `slice`:

```
$ irb
>> people = ["chris", "bob", "bill", "julie"]
=> ["chris", "bob", "bill", "julie"]
>> letter = gets.chomp.downcase
B
=> "b"
>> people.select { |person| person[0,1] == letter }
=> ["bob", "bill"]
```

Also, there's no need to add the `to_s` to the `gets.chomp`; you should already have a string.

In Ruby 1.9, you could instead do:

```
>> people.select { |person| person[0] == letter }
=> ["bob", "bill"]
```

In Ruby 1.9, indexing into a string always returns a string; in earlier versions, indexing with a single value into a string gets you a character. Another alternative, which should work in all versions, would be:

```
>> people.select { |person| person[0] == letter[0] }
=> ["bob", "bill"]
```

Comment: Because person[0] would return the code of the character at the first position.

Comment: I've added some clarification about why you don't do `person[0]`, which actually does work in Ruby 1.9.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to remove the elements from the original array as well as put them in a new array, take a look at partition

```
>> people = "chris,george,jerry,bob,bill,julie,josh".split(",")
=> ["chris", "george", "jerry", "bob", "bill", "julie", "josh"]
>> bs, people = people.partition {|name| name[0,1] == 'b'}
=> [["bob", "bill"], ["chris", "george", "jerry", "julie", "josh"]]
>> bs
=> ["bob", "bill"]
>> people
=> ["chris", "george", "jerry", "julie", "josh"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you could use select:

```
people.select {|person| person[0,1] == letter}
```

Here is an example implementation. First, we have a unit test describing what needs to happen:

```
class PeopleListTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
   def setup
      @people = PeopleList.new "jack", "jill", "bruce", "billy"
   end

   def test_starting_with
      assert_equal ["bruce", "billy"], @people.starting_with("b")    
      assert_equal ["jack", "jill"], @people.starting_with("j")    
      assert_equal [], @people.starting_with("q")    
   end
end
```

If this is what you are attempting to do, then the code to make that pass is:

```
class PeopleList
   def initialize *people
      @people = people    
   end

   def starting_with letter
      return @people.select {|person| person[0,1] == letter}
   end
end
```

I hope this helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This also works, albeit slightly less efficient than Brian's, but much more flexible.

```
>> a = ['bob', 'abe', 'fred', 'bill']
=> ["bob", "abe", "fred", "bill"]
>> a.select{|s| s =~ /^b/}
=> ["bob", "bill"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll get more mileage out of collect than you will from slice

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/Array.html#M000444